# SysCallError: (50, 'ENETDOWN')

Tags: python-3.x

I ran twitterscraper module last night, but failed because I got an error message.

I'd like to know what this message means? Is it that twitter blocked access?

```
ERROR: ConnectionError HTTPSConnectionPool(host='twitter.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /i/search/timeline?f=tweets&vertical=default&include_available_features=1&include_entities=1&reset_error_state=false&src=typd&max_position=cm+55m-bbEEaIaEIDXIaJaaDv-bbEEEEFXJbEsaFEvJF&q=%EC%A4%91%EA%B5%AD%20OR%20%EC%82%AC%EB%93%9C%20OR%20%EC%8B%B8%EB%93%9C%20OR%20Thaad%20OR%20THAAD%20since%3A2016-08-15%20until%3A2016-09-04&l=ko (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: SysCallError(50, 'ENETDOWN')"))) while requesting "https://twitter.com/i/search/timeline?f=tweets&vertical=default&include_available_features=1&include_entities=1&reset_error_state=false&src=typd&max_position=cm+55m-bbEEaIaEIDXIaJaaDv-bbEEEEFXJbEsaFEvJF&q=중국%20OR%20사드%20OR%20싸드%20OR%20Thaad%20OR%20THAAD%20since%3A2016-08-15%20until%3A2016-09-04&l=ko"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 444, in wrap_socket
    cnx.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1907, in do_handshake
    self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1631, in _raise_ssl_error
    raise SysCallError(errno, errorcode.get(errno))
OpenSSL.SSL.SysCallError: (50, 'ENETDOWN')
```